# How do i retrieve a value from method level scope?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

```
private void receive() {
            receive = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (running) {
                        byte[] data = new byte[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];
                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                    try {
                        socket.receive(packet);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String str = new String(packet.getData());
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            }
        }, "receive");
        receive.start();
    }
```

I need to retrieve a source port which would go like this:

```
packet.getPort()
```

but i cann't figure out how do i do that exactly. Every time i try, the value sets to zero when it goes out of scope so it only exists inside the run method, or even while loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting outer variable from anonymous inner class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977735/setting-outer-variable-from-anonymous-inner-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous classes can only refer to `final` variables, but such variables need not be [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). A good choice here is [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html):

```
final AtomicInteger port = new AtomicInteger();
```

then in your runnable:

```
port.set(packet.getPort());
```

then outside:

```
receive.start();
receive.join();
System.out.println(port.get());
```

You need the call to `join()` too, because `start()` isn't synchronous or deterministic. If the value is needed elsewhere, you could return/pass `port`, which is threadsafe.