# How can I create an object from a Firebase query in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an Android app with Kotlin, and I want to fill the `Customer` data class I've created with values from Firebase.

It's impossible to `return` from an `.addOnCompleteListener` after `.get`, therefore, I can't just `return Customer`, which would be ideal. I've read about `toObject`, but am not sure how to correctly use it (or if it does solve my problem).

`Customer.kt`:

```
data class Customer (
    val name: String,
    val phone: String,
    val address: String,
    val lastVisit: String,
    val lastVisitTimestamp: Timestamp,
    val latitude: Double,
    val longitude: Double
) : Serializable
```

Pseudo-code for what I want to achieve:

```
ref.whereEqualTo("name", name)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                val name = task.result?.documents!![0].data!!["name"].toString()
                val customer = Customer()
                customer.name = name
                // I want to return this customer object. That's what I can't do.
                return Customer()
            }
// and so on
```

Comment: I don't have one, but I'll put a generic one for example @a_local_nobody

Comment: Maybe edit the question to focus on the single problem at hand?  Please show code that you've tried and what didn't work the way you expect.

Comment: if you're looking for ways to get data from the async operation, this will work : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android/57330767#57330767

Comment: and to convert an object from firebase, all you have to do is something like :  `val response = result.toObject(Customer::class.java)`

Comment: @DougStevenson I've removed references to what I might do later with this class to avoid confusion, since that was supposed to be nothing but context. I haven't tried anything to be honest, I have no idea how to do this. I can use the data from the query inside the onComplete listener, but I don't know how to get it out of there.

Comment: look at this for help doing that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android/57330767#57330767

Comment: I think you might just want to start with the documentation to see how to get fields out of a DocumentSnapshot to pass to the constructor of your data class.  There is also plenty of API docs that walk you through each object and the methods they offer.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: @DougStevenson I know how to manipulate data INSIDE the onCompleteListener. I don't know how to get it out of there without a callback. I've added an example of what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: why not just use a callback ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Not to be rude or anything, but that doesn't really come to the case. Either ways. I'd like to start an activity and pass that object returned from the firebase query as an Extra, and use the values there.

Comment: Firebase loads data from its servers asynchronously. That means that your `return Customer()` will not work, because there's nobody listening. Any code that needs access to data from the database must be inside the completion listener, or be called from there. See for an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/51002413