# Kotlin-Firebase-cannot utilize the string read from database further down in the code

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have managed to read data from my firebase database but cant seem to re-use the String which has been read.

My successful read is as per below. When i check the logcat for the Log.d("Brand") it actually shows the String as expected.

```
brandchosenRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val brandsRef = brandchosenRef.child("CarList2").orderByChild("Car").equalTo(searchable_spinner_brand.selectedItem.toString())

    val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {


    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for(ds in dataSnapshot.children){
            Log.d("spinner brand",searchable_spinner_brand.selectedItem.toString())
            val Brand = ds.child("Brand").getValue(String::class.java)
            val brandselected= Brand.toString()

            Log.d("Brand","$brandselected")
         selectedbrand== brandselected

            Log.d("selected brand",selectedbrand)
        }
    }
    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("Branderror","error on brand")
    }

}
brandsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

What i am trying to do is write "selectedbrand" into a separate node using the following:

```
val carselected = searchable_spinner_brand.selectedItem.toString()

val dealref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Deal_Summary2")

val dealsummayId = dealref.push().key

val summaryArray = DealSummaryArray(dealsummayId.toString(),"manual input for testing","brand","Deal_ID",carselected,extrastext.text.toString(),otherinfo.text.toString(),Gauteng,WC,KZN,"Open")

dealref.child(dealsummayId.toString()).setValue(summaryArray).addOnCompleteListener{
    }
```

Note, in the above i was inputting "manual input for testing" to check that my write to Firebase was working and it works as expected. if i replace that with `selectedbrand`, then i get the below error.

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property selectedbrand has not been initialized

the summary array indicated above is defined in a separate class as follows. and as seen "manual input for testing is declared as String.

```
class DealSummaryArray(val id:String,val brand:String,val Buyer_ID:String,val Deal_ID:String,val Car:String,val extras:String,val other_info:String,val Gauteng:String,val Western_Cape:String,val KZN:String,val Status:String) {
constructor():this("","","","","","","","","","",""){
}
```

}

My question simply put, it why can i not re-use the value i read from the database? even if i was not trying to re-write it to a new node i cannot seem to utilize the value outside of the firebase query.

I seem to get this problem everywhere in my activities and have to find strange work around's like write to a textview and then reference the textview. please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, as it may take some time before you get a response from the server. To prevent blocking the application (which would be a bad experience for your users), your main code continues to run while the data is being loaded. And then when the data is available, Firebase calls your `onDataChange` method.

What this means in practice is that any code that needs the data from the database, needs to be **inside** the `onDataChange` method or be called from there. So any code that requires `selectedbrand` needs to be inside `onDataChange` or called from there (typically through a callback interface).

Also see:

- [How to check a certain data already exists in firestore or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000169/how-to-check-a-certain-data-already-exists-in-firestore-or-not/51002413#51002413), which contains example code including of the callback interface, in Java.
- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519), which contains a similar example for the Firebase Realtime Database.
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener), which shows a way to make the code behave more synchronous, and explains shows that this may not work on various Android versions.

Comment: Hi Frank. i am going to mark this as answered, becasue what you described is what i ahve been doing. i was hoping that there was an easier way. having said, that, taking into consideration that you mentioned the code must reside within onDataChange, why can't i use the Intent function within data change?