# Android studio Firebase query - retrieve value from Callback function and assign it to a variable

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am a beginner so apologies for a possible silly question.

I am trying to retrieve data from a Firebase database. This works but I cannot assign the value to a string variable for use later on.

This is the asynchronous call to the database which returns the right result. (The data its querying from is static so I don't really need an asynchronous call but as far as I am aware, I don't have another option).

```
 public static void getAnimalDetails(String strColl, final String strQueryField, final String strQueryValue,
                                         final MyCallBack myCallback){

        mfirebaseDb.collection(strColl)
                .whereEqualTo(strQueryField, strQueryValue)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                                    String strResult = document.get("animal_class").toString();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "SSSS:" + strResult );
                                    myCallback.onCallback(strResult);

                            }



                        }
                    }
                });

    }
```

This is the callback function passed to the method above.

```
    public interface MyCallBack {
        void onCallback(String strValFromAsyncTask);
    }
```

Then this is where I call the asynch task and try and access the data from the callback.
This method fires on a button click
I can see via the log that the right value is populated in strAnimalClass (which is a global variable)
But when I try to use strAnimalClass outside of the call back it is null.

```
        getAnimalDetails("animals", "animal_common_name", animal, new MyCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(String strValFromAsyncTask) {

                strAnimalClass = strValFromAsyncTask;
                Log.d(TAG, "mmmmm:" + strAnimalClass );
            }
        });
```

Can anyone help with how to get a value like this out of the async / callback environment for use later on?
Thank you

Comment: Are you saying that the log shows the "SSSS" line but not the "mmmm" line?  What exactly are you observing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the value outside of the callback. Or more specifically, you *can* use the value outside of the callback, but not before the callback has been called. This same rule applies to Firebase's `onComplete`  **and** to your custom `onCallback` method.

You can verify that with a few log lines:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Before calling getAnimalDetails")
getAnimalDetails("animals", "animal_common_name", animal, new MyCallBack() {
    @Override
    public void onCallback(String strValFromAsyncTask) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onCallback");
    }
});
Log.d(TAG, "After calling getAnimalDetails")
```

When you run this code, it logs:

> Before calling getAnimalDetails
>
> After calling getAnimalDetails
>
> Inside getAnimalDetails

So while you can access `strAnimalClass` after the code that calls `getAnimalDetails`, it won't have the expected value yet, because `onCallback` wasn't called yet.

For this reason any code that needs the value(s) from the database will need to be inside `onComplete` or inside `onCallback`, or be called from within there.

Also see:

- [How to check a certain data already exists in firestore or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000169/how-to-check-a-certain-data-already-exists-in-firestore-or-not/51002413#51002413)
- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)

Comment: Thank you so much, I suspected as much. I will try and run all the required code from within the callback or within the initial onCompleteListener