# Firebase Firestore fetches data but doesn't apply to an If Statement

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my project when a user presses on a button it sets the variable `clicked = true` and changes TextView colour to orange, the variable `clicked` is stored to a database in Firebase Firestore and fetched when activity is started. When I close the app and run it, the variable `clicked` is returned as true but it does not apply to my `if`statement and returns the TextView colour to default.

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        DocumentReference documentReference = ffstore.collection("user_progress").document(userId);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (userAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                    if (documentSnapshot.getBoolean("introOption_1_clicked") != null) {
                        clicked = (documentSnapshot.getBoolean("introOption_1_clicked"));
                        Log.i("Message", "Clicked is true "+  clicked);
                    } else {

                    }
                } else {

                }

            }
        });

        if (introOption1Class.returnintroFinishOp1Btn() == true) {
            progressTxt.setText("Finished");
            progressTxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#20df9a"));
            Log.i("MessageTF", "Op1");
        } else if (clicked == true) {
            progressTxt.setText("Started");
            progressTxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb000"));
            Log.i("MessageTF", "Op2");
        } else if (introOption2Class.returnintroFinishOp2Btn() == true && clicked == true) {
            progressTxt.setText("Finished");
            progressTxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#20df9a"));
            Log.i("MessageTF", "Op3");
        }

    }
```

Comment: what does your document look like ?

Comment: @LenaBru https://prnt.sc/r5e7be

Comment: your code that acts upon the mutable `clicked` `boolean` variable needs to react to its value/state in the `EventListener::onEvent` callback. Currenly the variable will always be `false` when the code runs.

Comment: it seems to me, that the entry points when You check the variable and setting the colors aren't the same...check [documentation of lifecycles](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: Data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, and while that is happening your main code path continues running (so that the user can keep using the app). You should be able to see this in your logcat output because `Message ` will appear before `MessageTF `. This means that any code that depends on the data from Firestore needs to be **inside** the `onEvent` method. See my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000169/how-to-check-a-certain-data-already-exists-in-firestore-or-not/51002413#51002413