# Upload data to firestore before activity is completely destroyed

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a quiz app. And I want that if the user kills the app their performance be uploaded on the firestore. When he clicks submit Button everything works fine but when I call submitbutton.callOnClick();
in onDestroy() some code is executed but the data is not uploaded.

this is my onDestroy() code

```
 protected void onDestroy() {

    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ------");
    if (clicked) { } 
    else
        {
        clicked = false;
        submitButton.callOnClick();
    }


    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: done");

    super.onDestroy();
```

And this is some code of submitButton 's onClickListener

```
 Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ----------------------");
            Result result=new Result(new String(ansString),new String(officialAnsString),correct,incorrect,not_attempted,marks);


            FireBase_Variables.db.collection(tName+"_result").document(currentUser.getUid()).set(result);

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ----------------------");
```

I can see the upper log in the logcat but not the lower one. Which means the line for uploading data is not executed.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to wait until the write operation is completed, before calling `super.onDestroy()`.

If we unroll the code into a single block, that'd be something like:

```
protected void onDestroy() {

    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ------");
    if (clicked) { } 
    else
        {
        clicked = false;
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ----------------------");
        Result result=new Result(new String(ansString),new String(officialAnsString),correct,incorrect,not_attempted,marks);

        FireBase_Variables.db.collection(tName+"_result").document(currentUser.getUid()).set(result).addOnCompleteListener(new new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: done");

                super.onDestroy();
            }
        });
    }
```

Also see: [How to check a certain data already exists in firestore or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000169/how-to-check-a-certain-data-already-exists-in-firestore-or-not/51002413#51002413)

*Note: I didn't compile/run this code, so there may be syntactic problems with it. If you encounter such problems, please try to solve them for yourself and use the `edit` link under the answer to fix them for folks who come here after you.*

In general you'll want to do the above somewhere else than in an `onDestroy` handler though, as that method is fairly unlikely to be called.