# DocuemntSnapshot on Android is one result late

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an `EditText` where I type an username. After I click "REGISTER", a function processes the username to check if it already exists:

```
public boolean usernameExists (String username) {

    database.collection("users").document(username).get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete (@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                usernameExists_result = task.getResult().exists();
            }
            else {
                task.getException().printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    return usernameExists_result;

}
```

where `database` and `usernameExists_result` are both fields. Of course, since the username is the documentID, this function should return `true` if the document (and so the username) exists, and `false` if it doesn't.

Now, the problem is the function - apart from the first call - always returns the value that it should have returned on the previous call.

For example, if on the first call the function returns `true` because the username already exists, and then I type another username that doesn't exist, the function will also return `true`. On the next call, it will return `false`, because that it what it should have returned on the previous call. And on the next call, it will return whatever it should have returned on the previous, and so on.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior? I can provide whatever info is needed.

Comment: Data is loaded from Firestore (and most modern web APIs) asynchronously. If you run in a debugger and set breakpoints, you'll see that your `return usernameExists_result` runs before `usernameExists_result = task.getResult().exists()` ever gets executed. For this reason any code that needs the data from Firestore must be inside `onComplete` or be called from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51002413/209103

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is not working like this. Try to avoid making a methood boolean INSTEAD just just go on.

Example here:- your button

```
private void setBtnRegister(){
   btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view){
          //Check all exception here. (incase editext is null)
          //and then put the code here instead that method boolean
          database.collection("users").document(username).get()
          .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete (@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                //Success, maybe go next step
          }
          else {
                //Fail 
          }
        }
    });
   }
   });
}
```

Comment: But if I do the data handling inside the listener, how do I separate it from the view for good programming practice?

Comment: @outsidethecave you can use Interface.