# Custom Object Retrieved from Firebase Always Has Null Attributes

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retreive a custom `User` object from Firebase as follows:

```
getUserFromDB(loggedInUserEmail);
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
viewModel.sendUser(loggedInUser);

//...

public void getUserFromDB(String userEmail) {
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(userEmail);
    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
        loggedInUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);

        Log.d("User Login", documentSnapshot.getId() + " => " + documentSnapshot.getData());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
}
```

However, the user being retreived always has null attributes.
[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iJm6.png) from when I was debugging.

Note: I made sure my `User` class has a public empty constructor and all the attributes have a getter method.

Comment: Do you have setter methods as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the user from the database is an asynchronous operation. While the data is being loaded, the main code continues and your `viewModel.sendUser(loggedInUser)` executes before the data is loaded. Then the success callback is fired and sets `loggedInUser`, but by that time the view model has already been initialized with the wrong value.

The rule is always quite simple: any code that needs data from the database, needs to be inside the success listener (or be called from there). So something like:

```
public void getUserFromDB(String userEmail) {
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(userEmail);
    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
        loggedInUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
        //  Initialize ViewModelProvider here
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
        viewModel.sendUser(loggedInUser);
    });
}
```

Also see:

- [How to check a certain data already exists in firestore or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000169/how-to-check-a-certain-data-already-exists-in-firestore-or-not/51002413#51002413)

Comment: I've been stuck on this for ages... Thank you so much!