# Firestore Android Java Get a value of a modified variable within an outer class

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a system that allows the user to search for a movie and get the average of the ratings that various users have given to that movie. The system is not too complicated. When a user creates a post that post will have an id and a title (and other data that we don't need now) and these two following structures will be created:

```
  root --- posts 
             |
             --- uid (c)
                  |
                  --- userPosts (d)
                        |
                        --- postId (c)
                        |     |
                        |     --- title: "Post Title"
                        |     |
                        |     --- date: 4/06/2021
                        |
                        --- postId (d)
                              |
                              --- title: "Post Title"
                              |
                              --- date: 08/06/2021
                              |
                              --- description: "this is the description of the post"
                              [...etc]
```

and this:

```
root --- filtrofos
              |
              ---filName
                        |
                         ---**Title Post** 
                                        |
                                        --uid
                                        | 
                                        --uid
                                        ...etc
```

At this point with a query I go to fetch all the **user Ids of the users who posted the post** (the film review) with the name that the user searched for and for each ID found I go to search for the desired post I use a whereEqualTo ( "title", name of the film searched)

At this point I find myself inside the posts with the desired name (that is the name searched by the user) **so I take the evaluation field each time and I go to add it to a variable for each round so as to make the sum of the evaluations.** Now I just have to do the average. **The problem is that I used queries with add on complete listener that are executed several times with a for loop, i can't figure out when the for loop ended and i can't get my value. Because if I tried to declare a variable outside of all of this and then tried to use it where I need it, I'd get this: Variable 'sum' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final**

**Would anyone have an idea how I could get the sum of all the evaluations outside the for loop?**

This is the code described above:

```
int somma = 0;
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("filtroFoS").document("filName").collection(txtFilmOrSer.getText().toString()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < QuerySnapshot > () {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < QuerySnapshot > task) {
  if (task.isSuccessful()) {

    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
      for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()) {
        //Toast.makeText(activity_filtroFilm.this, document.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String uId = document.getId().toString();

        Query userPostsRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("post").document(document.getId()).collection("userPosts").whereEqualTo("title", txtFilmOrSer.getText().toString());
        userPostsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < QuerySnapshot > () {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < QuerySnapshot > task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
              String postID = "";
              for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, document.getId() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                postID = document.getId();
                // Toast.makeText(activity_filtroFilm.this, postID + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("post").document(uId).collection("userPosts").document(postID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < DocumentSnapshot > () {
                  @Override
                  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < DocumentSnapshot > task) {
                    String valutation = task.getResult().getString("valutation");
                    somma += Integer.parseInt(valutation);

                  }
                });

              }

              Toast.makeText(activity_filtroFilm.this, sommas[0] + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              String finalPostID = postID;

            }
          }

        });

      }
    }

  }
}

});

}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to declare a variable outside of all of this and then tried to use it where I need it

This won't work. Any code that needs the data from the database, needs to be inside the callback.

> i can't figure out when the for loop ended

A common way of doing this is to either use [`Tasks.whenAll()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAll(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)) or simply keep a counter of how many items you have already loaded.

So in your innermost callback, that'd look something like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("post").document(uId).collection("userPosts").document(postID).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < DocumentSnapshot > () {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < DocumentSnapshot > task) {
    String valutation = task.getResult().getString("valutation");
    somma += Integer.parseInt(valutation);
    if (completedTaskCount++ == totalTaskCount) { //  Check if we're done
      ... Do what you need with the somma variable
    }
  }
});
```

Also see:

- [How to check a certain data already exists in firestore or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000169/how-to-check-a-certain-data-already-exists-in-firestore-or-not/51002413#51002413)
- [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value/57330767#57330767)
- [How to return a DocumentSnapShot as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method/48500679#48500679)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hadn't thought about using Tasks.whenAll (), it actually seems like a good solution. As soon as I can I test it.