# android callback with firestore not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, callback

i'm trying to get data from firestore and i want to get data before executing the rest of the code so i used callbacks
at first i created a class DbManger with a static methode and an interface

```
public class DbManager
{

    private static FirebaseFirestore db;
    private static FirebaseAuth auth;
    private static FirebaseUser currentUser;



    public static void getField(String uid,String key, FirebaseCallBack callBack) {
        db= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();

        db.collection(Keys.USERS_KEY).document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                String field = documentSnapshot.getString(key);
                callBack.onCallBack(field);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public interface FirebaseCallBack
    {
         void onCallBack(String field) ;
    }

}
```

in the other activity i tried to get data with the help of the DbManager class like that

```
if(currentUser!=null){
        DbManager.getField(currentUser.getUid(), Keys.ACCOUNT_TYPE_KEY, new DbManager.FirebaseCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onCallBack(String field) {
                accountType=field;
            }
        });
        
    }
if(accountType.equals(Keys.ADMIN_ACCOUNT_TYPE_KEY))
        selectFragment(new HomeFragment());
    else
        selectFragment(new ModulesFragment());
```

but i didn't get any data

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value) for some more info on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `if(accountType.equals(Keys.ADMIN_ACCOUNT_TYPE_KEY))` runs before `accountType=field`. The easiest way to see this is by adding some logging, or setting breakpoints on those line and running in the debugger.

The solution for this is always the same: the code that needs the data, needs to be in the callback that is invoked once the data is available. So the simplest fix for you is:

```
if(currentUser!=null){
    DbManager.getField(currentUser.getUid(), Keys.ACCOUNT_TYPE_KEY, new DbManager.FirebaseCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onCallBack(String field) {
            accountType=field;
            if(accountType.equals(Keys.ADMIN_ACCOUNT_TYPE_KEY))
                selectFragment(new HomeFragment());
            else
                selectFragment(new ModulesFragment());
        }
    });
}
```

Also see:

- [How to check a certain data already exists in firestore or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000169/how-to-check-a-certain-data-already-exists-in-firestore-or-not/51002413#51002413)
- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)