# How to get data from an anonymous class?

Tags: java, retrofit2

While i was learning `Dagger2` I made a naive service class that provides data assynchronously (in this case jokes from a [funny api](https://api.chucknorris.io/)) but I encountered a problem and I kind of stuck with it. I'm using `retrofit2` for requesting data from network.

But I can't figure out how to **pull out** the `joke` object retrieved from network (via `response.body()`), from anonymous internal class, into `joke` instance variable of the external class. I'm getting `NullPointerException`:

```
public class ChuckNorrisJokeService {
private Joke joke;

public String getJoke() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://api.chucknorris.io")
            .build();

    JokeService jokeService = retrofit.create(JokeService.class);
    Call<Joke> call = jokeService.provideJoke();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Joke>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Joke> call, Response<Joke> response) {
            joke = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Joke> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());
        }
    });

    return joke.getContent();
}
}
```

The `Joke` class is a simple POJO:

```
public class Joke {
@SerializedName("value")
private String content;

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
}
```

**P.S.** When calling synchronously the result is successful. *How can I achieve the same functionality asynchronously?*

**P.S.S.** I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977735/setting-outer-variable-from-anonymous-inner-class) but it doesn't work for me and is so dirty.

**The stacktrace is this:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.alic.ChuckNorrisJokeService.getJoke(ChuckNorrisJokeService.java:41)
at com.alic.Application.run(Application.java:11)
at com.alic.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

The `Application` and `Main` classes are very simple:

```
public class Application {
private ChuckNorrisJokeService chuckNorrisJokeService;

public Application() {
    this.chuckNorrisJokeService = new ChuckNorrisJokeService();
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println(chuckNorrisJokeService.getJoke());
}
}
```

and the `Main` class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application app = new Application();
    app.run();
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace for your exception.

Comment: `call.enqueue(new Callback<Joke>() {...})` is a thread callback, when you run `joke.getContent()`, maybe not yet run `onResponse` to init data.

Comment: Well, my question was how to solve this issue. I'm aware about callbacks and stuff. I asked because I hoped someone encountered the same issue like me and I hoped for a solution (a workaround maybe).

Comment: How do you do this synchronously? You should always get `NetworkOnMainThread` exception with Android 4.0 and above.

Comment: I just made a gradle project in intellij idea. There's no android code here.  It's just plain old java with retrofit library for managing networking. I was fulling around with dependency injection and dagger2 container when I encountered this  _java_ problem.

Comment: @AndritchiAlexei Sorry I thought you are asking in Android :(

Comment: I was specifically abstracting from android ecosystem just to concentrate on learning dagger2 library.